# JS use a function from two different sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three radio buttons, the selection of each of the buttons change the content inside the #show div.
when the page loads the div contains a dinamic form and it works perfectley.
after i select one of the radio buttons and than go back to the form situation the dynamic form do not add more fields.

i am kind of new to JS and i can't spot the problem.
any help will be great.

i am not sure what is the problem so
any suggestion for better question title will be accepted

this is the dynamic field function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addm").click(function () {
            var intIdm = $("#buildyourformm div").length + 1;
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" name=\"field[]\" id=\"fieldm" + intIdm + "\"/>");
            var wfnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\field 1\"  name=\"inputwFname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");
            var wlnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"field 2\"  name=\"inputwLname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");


            var removeButtonm = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove-btn btn-warning\" value=\"remove\" />");
            removeButtonm.click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            fieldWrapper.append(wfnamem);
            fieldWrapper.append(wlnamem);
            fieldWrapper.append(removeButtonm);
            $("#buildyourformm").append(fieldWrapper);
        });
    });
```

this is a link to what i have done already

http://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/ca7gvrkp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that you did not delegate a click handler on the add button, so when you maniulate the dom ( removing appending) the bind to the specific id wont work because you removed the element i also merged the click handler into your ready function, you dont need two ready functions

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        var n = $(this).val();
        switch(n)
        {
                case '1':
                      $('#show').html('<fieldset id="buildyourformm"><div name="field1" id="field1"><div><input type="text" placeholder="field 1"  name="inputwFname[]"></div><div><input type="text" placeholder="field 2" name="inputwLname[]" class="form-control"></div><input type="button"  value="remove"></div></fieldset><input type="button" value="add" id="addm" /><br><br><br></div></div></div></fieldset>');
                      break;
                case '2':
                      $('#show').html("2nd radio button");
                      break;
                case '3':
                      $('#show').html("3rd radio button");
                      break;
            }
        });


            $("#show").on("click","#addm",function (event) {
                var intIdm = $("#buildyourformm div").length + 1;
                var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" name=\"field[]\" id=\"fieldm" + intIdm + "\"/>");
                var wfnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\field 1\"  name=\"inputwFname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");
                var wlnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"field 2\"  name=\"inputwLname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");


                var removeButtonm = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove-btn btn-warning\" value=\"remove\" />");
                removeButtonm.click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });

                fieldWrapper.append(wfnamem);
                fieldWrapper.append(wlnamem);
                fieldWrapper.append(removeButtonm);
                $("#buildyourformm").append(fieldWrapper);
            });
    });
```

note that this wont work with jquery 1.6, if you realy need to use this old version, change .on to .live

heres a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ca7gvrkp/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the very first time your document ready function is attaching the eventhandlers to the UI buttons, but when you select another radio button and come back to the form again, though it appears to be the same form, IT IS NOT. Because as per your code, based on the radio button, you are rendering the controls again. But this time, the document ready will not be executed, since it is not actually a refresh.

I have modified your code a little bit, check this fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    switch(n)
    {
            case '1':
                  $('#show').html('<fieldset id="buildyourformm"><div name="field1" id="field1"><div><input type="text" placeholder="field 1"  name="inputwFname[]"></div><div><input type="text" placeholder="field 2" name="inputwLname[]" class="form-control"></div><input type="button"  value="remove"></div></fieldset><input type="button" value="add" id="addm" /><br><br><br></div></div></div></fieldset>');
                  tieEvents();
                  break;
            case '2':
                  $('#show').html("2nd radio button");
                  break;
            case '3':
                  $('#show').html("3rd radio button");
                  break;
        }
    });
});




$(document).ready(function () {
    tieEvents();
        });

function tieEvents() {
    $("#addm").click(function () {
            var intIdm = $("#buildyourformm div").length + 1;
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" name=\"field[]\" id=\"fieldm" + intIdm + "\"/>");
            var wfnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\field 1\"  name=\"inputwFname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");
            var wlnamem = $("<div class=\"col-sm-5\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"field 2\"  name=\"inputwLname[]\" class=\"form-control\"></div>\" ");


            var removeButtonm = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove-btn btn-warning\" value=\"remove\" />");
            removeButtonm.click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            fieldWrapper.append(wfnamem);
            fieldWrapper.append(wlnamem);
            fieldWrapper.append(removeButtonm);
            $("#buildyourformm").append(fieldWrapper);
        });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ca7gvrkp/6/